# GsaIOException Buffer overflow, no available space

Tags: android, exception, video-streaming

I have a MediaPlayer app with a live streaming function. When I test the app with a physically device(API 22 Lollipop and API 23 Marshmallow) there are no problems with starting of the stream.
Today I want to test the application with a Emulator (API 25 Nougat). Stream is not working and I get the following error:

> (SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
>   02-23 23:58:09.834 2166-3554/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
>                                                                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
>                                                                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)

I can recognize only one thing where I think it is important.

> GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space

But I don't know what it could mean. Can anyone explain what kind of Exception it is. And where I can search at the code to find the problem?

Comment: not sure, but did you mount an sdcard on your virtual device?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, for me it was crashing on devices too, with the same error. This is how I fixed it for devices:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

More details here: [Looping Error on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164577/looping-error-on-android-emulator/45462655#45462655)

To make the app work on simulator, after applying the fix from the above link, I had to create a new simulator based on x86 architecture (not x86_64 as before) and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting these exact messages while trying to debug my device with logcat. Could not figure out where they were coming from.  Finally realized that a preceding debug session with the emulator was generating these.  I simply quit the emulator to stop them.

Comment: This also worked for me, fully restarting the emulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did receive the same issue, and i did the following things to make this crash occurs.
Few api's that i wrote needed to allocate some memory since a file needed to be parsed and kept in that buffer. I started parsing the file without allocating the buffer hence received that message.
So you could look into similar code where you might be doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by deleting the apk files that i have created before and they still remain in Project Files list.