# My App has stopped error on android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I got this message when I tried to run my app on android studio's emulator "App has stopped".

this is the logcat :

```
2644-4713/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
  com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
   Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
      at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
      at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

How can I solve this ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to listen on microphone through your app??  @MSCS

Comment: This occurs on emulator only & not on real device. Hardware insufficiency issue

Comment: @07AndroidLover , it's a simple game

Comment: @VVB I had the same issue in real device

Answer (score 0):

```
 Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
```

Your target version android sdk? Maybe 24? --> You try to dropdown version target version adnroid sdk 23 or lower

Reference more info follow link:
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

Comment: minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: Hi @MSCS Please try to using Android SDK 23 or lower to build and target version.

Comment: Are you trying to listen on microphone through your app??

Comment: @Huỳnh Ngọc Bang I'm tried to lower it but some error occured , it says that the Minimum sdk required is 25.0.0 , how can I solve that ?

Comment: Do you know the Android-APIs that you are using require sdk-version min 25.

Comment: Android is trying to listen on the microphone?

Comment: If so, please ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164577/looping-error-on-android-emulator