# onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)

Tags: java, android, gradle, logcat, repeat

I am getting the following error on logcat repeatedly.I am also posting my gradle informations.

```
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
  Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6) 
03-24 15:35:38.429 2681-8715/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
03-24 15:35:38.444 2681-2681/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
03-24 15:35:38.444 2681-2681/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
03-24 15:35:38.446 2681-11725/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
03-24 15:35:39.909 12694-12694/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
03-24 15:35:40.007 12694-12694/? W/app_process: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
03-24 15:35:40.051 12694-12694/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
03-24 15:35:40.072 1736-4225/system_process W/WindowManager: Permission Denial: dismissKeyguard from pid=12694, uid=2000 requires android.permission.CONTROL_KEYGUARD
03-24 15:35:40.073 12694-12694/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

my build-gradle(module) file has

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

my build_gradle (project) file has the following

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping Error on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164577/looping-error-on-android-emulator)

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you solved it?