# W AppOps : Noting op not finished: pkg com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, adb, gmsmapview

Upgrading to RN 0.60.5 and the app is keep stopping. I run `adb logcat` and got  a lot of errors which refer to `com.google.android.gms` package.

some of the errors:

```
09-04 19:38:08.102  2893  3069 I MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
09-04 19:38:08.104  2893  3069 W ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 393244, bug: 0]: errorCode: 393244, engine: 0
09-04 19:38:08.106  2893  3069 I MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
09-04 19:38:08.106  2893  3069 I MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
09-04 19:38:08.106  2893 25752 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
09-04 19:38:13.109  2893  3069 I MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
09-04 19:38:13.110  2893  3069 W ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 393244, bug: 0]: errorCode: 393244, engine: 0
09-04 19:38:13.111  2893  3069 I MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
09-04 19:38:13.111  2893  3069 I MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
09-04 19:38:13.111  2893 25752 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
09-04 19:38:13.212  1941  4667 W AppOps  : Noting op not finished: uid 10098 pkg com.google.android.gms code 41 time=1567625887233 d
uration=0
```

What should I do?

Comment: Found any solution for this issue?

Comment: Any solution  for this ???

Comment: please any solution for this ? i'm facing it too

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was using http:// in my HttpClient calls.  After switching to https:// the messages went away.

Answer (score -1):

I've been through this problem. Android is trying to listen to the microphone, which is not available on the emulator, so it fills the logcat with useless stack traces. To stop this, go to the Settings app on Android and click:

1. Apps and notifications
2. Application permissions
3. Microphone

Then, do not allow the use of a microphone for all applications.

[Looping Error on Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164577/looping-error-on-android-emulator)