# com.google.android.apps.gcs causes app to crash on launch in Emulator

Tags: android

I have an Android 9 Emulator in Android Studio, and I'm trying to run my app on it.

However app crashes on launch, and it keeps logging this lengthy error:

```
2018-10-08 11:48:28.693 18207-18309/? E/aise: Phenotype API error. Event a <
      a: ""
      b: 0
      d: 1
      e: "com.google.android.apps.gcs"
      f: 0
      g: 0
      h: 0
      i: ""
      j: ""
    >
    d: 219
    g: # bpkh@f5738319
    , EventCode: 12
    [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aira: 29503
        at aisl.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):36)
        at aisk.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):5)
        at aise.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):85)
        at aise.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):77)
        at wsj.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):29)
        at bdmu.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):2)
        at pyx.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at qet.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-10-08 11:48:28.693 18207-18309/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at aise.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):95)
        at aise.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):77)
        at wsj.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):29)
        at bdmu.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):2)
        at pyx.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at qet.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2018-10-08 11:48:28.694 18207-18250/? E/NetRec: [530] afrj.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: otp: 29503: 
        at aptv.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):2)
        at aptv.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):28)
        at afrj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):1)
        at afrj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):4)
        at afrg.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):6)
        at psm.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):1)
        at bmj.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):5)
        at psn.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):14)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):6)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):2)
     Caused by: otp: 29503: 
        at ozf.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):4)
        at aipu.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):5)
        at aisk.a(Unknown Source:3)
        at wsg.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):5)
        at wsj.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):37)
        at bdmu.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):2)
        at pyx.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280040@13.2.80 (100700-211705629):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at qet.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164577/looping-error-on-android-emulator/45462655) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428565/gsaioexception-buffer-overflow-no-available-space?rq=1), but disabling microphone permissions and Google search app haven't solved my problem.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: could you find a solution for the problem?

Comment: Nope, as I remember I had to reinstall things.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem when I am developing a map application with a locate part in it.
It seems work fine that I could see the GPS icon on the top of the screen, however, it can't move the 'camera' to my real location.

From the log category, I found this error message 'Could not retrieve server token for package `com.google.android.apps.gcs'` which I thought could be the most likely reason that I couldn't get it through.

I've tried some small changes on project configuration until I tried to downgrade the `compileSdkVersion` to lower level. For this project, I changed it from `28` to `27`. (My mobile phone is equipped with Android 9.)

Then it works.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore since Google mandated migration to API 29 in November. Anything else we can do about it?