# meteor mobile app does not work on android 9 and 10

Tags: android, meteor, meteor-mobile, mobile-config

I made a mobile app from a meteor project.
The app works well on Android 7 and 8.

But it does not work on Android 9 and 10. The login page is displayed on the mobile but I can not login.
It seems that the request is not sent to the server and after clicking on the login, the loading mode remains.

[image]

I have installed version 29 of the SDK on the system. And here is my mobile-config.js.

```
App.info({
  id: 'com.marco.android.karname',
  name: 'karname',
  description: 'Debug mode',
  author: 'Matt Development Group',
  email: 'contact@example.com',
  website: 'http://example.com',
  version: "0.0.3"
});

App.icons({
  'android_xxhdpi': 'resources/icons/en-logo.png',
});

App.launchScreens({
  'android_mdpi_portrait': 'resources/icons/sample.png',
});

App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0xff0000ff');
App.setPreference('HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar', true);
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'default');
App.setPreference('Orientation', 'all', 'ios');

App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '30');
App.setPreference('android-minSdkVersion', '24');

App.appendToConfig(`
  <universal-links>
    <host name="http://192.168.0.66" />
  </universal-links>
`);
```

and here is my logcat:

```
..
2020-10-07 19:08:03.096 2157-3396/? E/aofp: Phenotype API error. Event # bybz@5dc8807f, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
    aoeg: 29503
        at aofv.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):23)
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):92)
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):79)
        at aale.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):19)
        at bkdz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at squ.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):37)
        at squ.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at swz.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-07 19:08:03.099 2157-3396/? E/AsyncOperation: serviceID=51, operation=GetCommittedConfigurationOperationCall
    OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 29503, resolution=null}]
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):100)
        at aofp.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):79)
        at aale.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):19)
        at bkdz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at squ.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):37)
        at squ.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at swz.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-07 19:08:03.100 2157-3786/? E/NetRec: [88] alcj.a: Could not retrieve server token for package com.google.android.apps.gcs
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: rjk: 29503: 
        at avgu.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):3)
        at avgu.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):20)
        at alcj.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):1)
        at alcj.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):4)
        at alce.getHeaders(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):9)
        at sjg.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):1)
        at byj.executeRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):1)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):5)
        at sjj.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):13)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):7)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
     Caused by: rjk: 29503: 
        at rpj.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):4)
        at aodi.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at aofv.a(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):6)
        at aale.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):30)
        at bkdz.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):2)
        at squ.b(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):37)
        at squ.run(:com.google.android.gms@17786022@17.7.86 (040700-256199907):21)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at swz.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-07 19:08:03.100 2157-3786/? W/NetRec: [88] alcj.a: No server tokens extracted.
2020-10-07 19:08:03.107 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 6
2020-10-07 19:08:03.111 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
2020-10-07 19:08:03.128 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 6
2020-10-07 19:08:03.131 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
..


..
2020-10-07 19:10:58.926 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 6
2020-10-07 19:10:58.933 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
2020-10-07 19:10:58.936 1747-2376/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2020-10-07 19:10:58.936 1747-2376/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2020-10-07 19:10:58.983 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 1 (1) 1 6
2020-10-07 19:10:58.986 12822-12869/com.marco.android.karname D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
..
```

Comment: is this IP address `<host name="http://192.168.0.66" />` is always the same?

Comment: @isthemartin yes

Comment: Can you share us the logcat?

Comment: @isthemartin
I edited the question.

Comment: It is constantly logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55507576/8815526), I reduced the targetSdkVersion version from 30 to 27 in mobile-config.js. And now it is working.

```
App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '27');
App.setPreference('android-minSdkVersion', '24');
```